# Sold a call option and it expired out of the money and I was in debt?

Tags: trading, options

this is just eating my brain away, I couldn't find the solution on my own so I'm here to see if anyone could help me.

Today was the last trading day of options on VIX, I sold 5 Call options at 0.05 with the strike price of 18, the stock closed at 15.57 and the thinkorswim platform takes 1$ fee for every trade so.... total profits 25$ - 5$ fee, which means I should have been 20$ in the green but apparently I'm at minus (112$) ?? Please make sense of this because I'm lost right now.

Note; The stock was trading at 15$ - 16$ when I sold the calls and never reached 18$.
Note; This was done on the thinkorswim platform paper trading.

Comment: If I understand right, "paper trading" means this is a practice account?  In reality, a call could be assigned based on a human's decision even out of the money (in particular if there is a dividend).  Does the paper trading system state what rules it implements about call assignment?

Comment: This is the VIX so there's no dividend.  IRL, if an OTM call was assigned (infinitesimal chance of  that happening), it would result in free money and the position would be positive.  It's a paper trading account so there's no counter party to exercise early.

Comment: @RaniFaris - Based on the information that you presented, it makes no sense.  There must be something else going on that you're not seeing.

Comment: @BobBaerker - thanks. "Paper Trading" - I didn't notice this until I read your comment. You agree, if the VIX never went above 18, the option premium, less commission, is profit. The rest makes no sense.

Comment: When I sold the 5 calls and the stock never reached the 18$ strike price mark, the thinkorswim platform showed me that I was (112$) in debt instead of being 20$ in the green,but the very next day it says that days until expiry -1 and P/L Day +11.25$ on the trade, I mean where did the minus (112$) come from at first? And how was it changed to +11.25 the next day?
Plus why is it at 11.25 in the green instead 20? The math doesn't add up.

Comment: Joe - as you stated in  your comment to the deleted answer, if assigned, he'd be short at $18, and have a tidy profit when he covered the short. But since it never went above $18, the position would have a profit at expiration.  Yes, it makes no sense.

Comment: @RaniFaris - The VIX has a funky AM settlement sothe time at which  you looked at the P&L might be a factor as to P&L.  If the P&L is +$11.25, it was  being based on an option that still had some value (I'd guess that TOS averages the B/A as the basis).  I'd suggest that you chalk the question about the -$112  to "Who Knows?" and that the next time you sell a naked option position, you carefully jot down all of the relevant information (or do a screen capture) so the position can be evaluated properly.

Comment: Probably chalk it up to a bug in the paper trading platform. VRO (the VIX settlement value) for 2/6/2019 was 15.4, so you should have made a profit of $25 less commission. Assuming you sold the 2/6/2019 calls.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly due to restrictions (or cost) of live market data, their platform may not have used the $15.57 closing price.  It is common for there to be such market data *artifacts* with paper trading platforms.

I would follow up with think-or-swim technical support to get more insight (good luck).